# Convert the page data extracted from pdf file into csv file using PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

I have extracted data from a pdf file, but I am unable to convert it into a csv file

import PyPDF2 as PDF

PDFfile = open("path", "rb")

pdfread = PDF.PdfFileReader(PDFfile)

page = pdfread.getpage(0)

Page_content = page.extractText()

After extracting the text from a particular page, I want to export it to a csv file. How to do this?

Comment: can you give us a text sample and a desired output ?

Comment: Hi, the output is not important, but I am unable to convert a page into csv file. Please help me in this.

Comment: do you have a separator in your text ? like "," or ";" ? If so, you should specify this to pandas : df.to_csv("file.csv", sep=";")